# Code doesn't want to run

Tags: java

I have to create a Java project that will read in a text file as an island and randomly move a mouse 100 times and decide if the mouse escaped, starved, or drowned. I have 2 classes. My first class is:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

   public class Island {


public char island [][];
private int  MoveCount = 0, StarveCount = 0, DrownCount = 0, EscapeCount = 0;
public  int mouse = 1;

    public void mouseIsland(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        island = new char [0][0];
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(file.hasNextLine()) {  
        ArrayList<String> lines1= new ArrayList<String>();
        String line= file.nextLine();
        lines1.add(line);    
        island=new char[lines1.size()][];
                }

            }


    public void moveLeft() {
       char[][] temp = island;
        if(MoveCount == 100){
            System.out.println("The mouse starved");
            StarveCount++;
            MoveCount = 0;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<island.length; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<island[i].length; ++j)
                if(MoveCount <100 && island[i][j] == '-'){
                    temp[i][j] = island[i][j-1]; 
                    MoveCount++;
                        if(temp[i][j] == '#'){
                            System.out.println("The mouse drowned after moving "+MoveCount+" times.");
                            DrownCount++;
                            MoveCount = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(temp[0][j] == '-' || temp [island.length-1][j] == '-' || temp [i][0] == '-' || temp[i][island[0].length-1] == '-'){
                            System.out.println("The mouse found a bridge and escaped after "+MoveCount+" times.");
                            EscapeCount++;
                            MoveCount = 0;
                            break;
                        }

        mouse = temp[i][j];
        temp[i][j] = (char) (MoveCount+1);
        island = temp;    
                }   
    }

        public void moveRight() {
           char[][] temp = island;
            if(MoveCount == 100){
                System.out.println("The mouse starved");
                StarveCount++;
                MoveCount = 0;
            }
            for(int i=0; i<island.length; ++i)
                for(int j=0; j<island[i].length; ++j)
                    if(MoveCount <100 && island[i][j] == '-'){
                        temp[i][j] = island[i][j+1]; 
                        MoveCount++;
                            if(temp[i][j] == '#'){
                                System.out.println("The mouse drowned after moving "+MoveCount+" times.");
                                DrownCount++;
                                MoveCount = 0;
                                break;
                            }
                            else if(temp[0][j] == '-' || temp [island.length-1][j] == '-' || temp [i][0] == '-' || temp[i][island[0].length-1] == '-'){
                                System.out.println("The mouse found a bridge and escaped after "+MoveCount+" times.");
                                EscapeCount++;
                                MoveCount = 0;
                                break;
                            }
            mouse = temp[i][j];
            temp[i][j] = (char) (MoveCount+1);
            island = temp;    
                    } 
        }

    public void moveUp() {
        char[][] temp = island;
        if(MoveCount == 100){
            System.out.println("The mouse starved");
            StarveCount++;
            MoveCount = 0;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<island.length; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<island[i].length; ++j)
                if(MoveCount <100 && island[i][j] == '-'){
                    temp[i][j] = island[i-1][j]; 
                    MoveCount++;
                        if(temp[i][j] == '#'){
                            System.out.println("The mouse drowned after moving "+MoveCount+" times.");
                            DrownCount++;
                            MoveCount = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(temp[0][j] == '-' || temp [island.length-1][j] == '-' || temp [i][0] == '-' || temp[i][island[0].length-1] == '-'){
                            System.out.println("The mouse found a bridge and escaped after "+MoveCount+" times.");
                            EscapeCount++;
                            MoveCount = 0;
                            break;
                        }
        mouse = temp[i][j];
        temp[i][j] = (char) (MoveCount+1);
        island = temp;    
                } 
    }

    public void moveDown(){
    char[][] temp = island;
        if(MoveCount == 100){
            System.out.println("The mouse starved");
            StarveCount++;
            MoveCount = 0;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<island.length; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<island[i].length; ++j)
                if(MoveCount <100 && island[i][j] == '-'){
                    temp[i][j] = island[i+1][j]; 
                    MoveCount++;
                        if(temp[i][j] == '#'){
                            System.out.println("The mouse drowned after moving "+MoveCount+" times.");
                            DrownCount++;
                            MoveCount = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if(temp[0][j] == '-' || temp [island.length-1][j] == '-' || temp [i][0] == '-' || temp[i][island[0].length-1] == '-'){
                            System.out.println("The mouse found a bridge and escaped after "+MoveCount+" times.");
                            EscapeCount++;
                            MoveCount = 0;
                            break;
                        }
        mouse = temp[i][j];
        temp[i][j] = (char) (MoveCount+1);
        island = temp;    
                } 
}

    public  void moveMouse (){   
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            int randomNumber = 1+(int)(Math.random()*(4));
                if(randomNumber == 1);
                    moveUp();
                if(randomNumber == 2);
                    moveDown();
                if(randomNumber == 3);
                    moveLeft();
                if(randomNumber == 4);
                    moveRight();
        }   
    }

    public String printStats(){
        return "The mouse starved this many times: "+StarveCount+
                "\nThe mouse escaped this many times: "+EscapeCount+
                "\nThe mouse drowned this many times: "+DrownCount;
    }


   }`
```

Here is my second class:

```
public class Exercise12Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Island i1 = new Island();
    i1.mouseIsland("mouseEscapeIsland-1.txt");
    System.out.println("Mouse Escape Island 1");
    System.out.println("The Coordinates of the bridges are: (0,1) & (2,11)");
    System.out.println("The Mouse is Starting at (7,6)");
    i1.moveMouse();
    i1.printStats();

}
```

}

and here is my island:

```
#-##########
#----------#
#-----------
#----------#
#----------#
#----------#
#----------#
#-----X----#
#----------#
#----------#
#----------#
############
```

Every time I try and run this code, I keep getting an error:
    Exception in thread "main" 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
       at Island.moveUp(Island.java:97)
       at Island.moveMouse(Island.java:154)
       at Exercise12Main.main(Exercise12Main.java:13)

Comment: Care to tell us what kind of an error you're getting?

Comment: why do people never get the idea that it might be useful to know the error....

Comment: the error i get is:Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Island.moveUp(Island.java:97)
 at Island.moveMouse(Island.java:154)
 at Exercise12Main.main(Exercise12Main.java:13)

Comment: There's no such thing as "An error" or program "not wanting to run". Tell us what the EXACT error is if you want help. If you only tell us that you have "an error", the best we can do is give you "a solution".

Comment: By the way, loops without brackets is asking `for` trouble. Don't do it.

Comment: `Code doesn't want to run` ?? OMG try to persuade her with bit of debugging

Comment: which line is line 97?

Comment: for(int j=0; j<island[i].length; ++j){

Comment: I believe that's because you never initialize the array properly.

Comment: In order that we can help you effectively, you should give us as little code possible (see http://sscce.org/) and describe your problem as much as possible (i.e. give all error messages, not just "it doesn't run"). Also, to ask questions like "here's my code, find a bug for me" is not very good.

Answer (score 0):

Google "Java Naming Conventions" and follow it.

For your error: You initialize `island` like this in your `mouseIsland` method:

```
island=new char[lines1.size()][];
```

So you have an char array of nulls, and now you try to access `island[0].length` here in `moveMouse` method:

```
for(int j=0; j<island[i].length; ++j)
```

and you get an `NullPointerException` because `island[0]` is `null`.

These kind of errors you can also find really easily if you use the debugger ;-)

Comment: Edgar bods, it seems you have a quite experience with using debugger. can you suggest a good tutorial?